# Using a parameter to filter out multiple values in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

In my query (note that I'm NOT using a procedure) I need to use a Boolean parameter that will define whether to filter out certain records or not.

My parameter's name is "WO" (= without). So - if the user chooses `&WO = 'TRUE'` I want some records to be filtered out.

My approach was to use a 'case when' in the where clause as following:

```
select *
from tbl1
where case when &WO = 'TRUE' then tbl1.field1 not in ('AB','CD','EF') end
```

I know the syntax or my whole approach are incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `case` like that; the result of a `case` needs to be compared with something. You could do this:

```
select *
from tbl1
where nvl('&WO', 'FALSE') != 'TRUE'
or tbl1.field1 not in ('AB','CD','EF')
```

If the first part of the `or` equates to false - that is, `&WO` is null or not `TRUE` - then the second part is not evaluated.

Comment: What about `&WO is null` ?

Comment: If `&WO is null` then your code would filter out `field1` values `AB`, `CD` and `EF`.  This is incorrect.

Comment: thanks so much! that was brilliant :) I changed your answer a bit to : select * from tbl1 where &WO != 'yes' or tbl1.field1 not in ('AB','CD','EF'). I changed it since using the nvl that way always gave me 'false'. MANY THANKS! :)

Comment: @user2399060 - that's basically what I started with, and Egor pointed out the flaw. Your question had `TRUE`. If you actually have `yes` then `nvl('&WO', 'no') != 'yes' or ...` would handle the `WO` value being set to null.